# Is $\mid iIm(z) \mid $ equals to $\mid Im(z) \mid $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I could define $iIm(z)$ like $iIm(z)=0+iIm(z)$ and apply the formula of the module which would return just Im(z). But I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: It is equal since $\mid i \mid$ =1

Comment: $|ab|=|a|\cdot |b|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z = a + ib$ then $|i \mathrm{Im}(z)| = |ib| = |b| = |\mathrm{Im}(z)|$. More generally, you have $|z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$ for all $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ so
$$ |i \mathrm{Im}(z)| = |i| |\mathrm{Im}(z)| = |\mathrm{Im}(z)| $$
since $|i| = 1$.

Comment: In the case I use $|z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$ My $z_1$ would be $i$ and $z_2$ $Im(z)$ right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$|i\Im z|=|i||\Im z|=|\Im z|$$